The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process - C#
I am getting a the above error intermittently when the .exe is running my application. I have created a series of event logs to track when it is failing and it seems pretty consistently happening at this point, although it has failed elsewhere once before. I believe this is the case because my event log is left blank when I open it before clicking "continue" on the unhandled exception pop-up.
I am new to C#, but have gotten the application running other than this issue. I am posting as a possible duplicate as I have embedded my StreamWriter statement into using statements, and applied other items from different questions with no improvement.
File.WriteAllText("EventLog_SlagModel.txt", String.Empty);


//load historical slag test heat numbers
Code_Triggered = true; //prevents the comboBox_IndexChange from triggering it's script when reloaded
this.v_SLAG_DATATableAdapter.Fill(this.bRSDBDataSet.V_SLAG_DATA);
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("EventLog_SlagModel.txt"))
{
    sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " - Historical Slag Sample List Loaded");
    sw.Dispose();
}
Code_Triggered = false; //prevents the comboBox_IndexChange from triggering it's script when reloaded


//event log
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("EventLog_SlagModel.txt"))
{
    sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " - EAF2 Live Mode Cycle Restarted");
    sw.Dispose();
}

conn.Open();
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("EventLog_SlagModel.txt"))
{
    sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " - Connection Opened");
    sw.Dispose();
}

Heat_Number = Convert.ToInt64(new SqlCommand("SQL Code to confidential db", conn).ExecuteScalar());
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("EventLog_SlagModel.txt"))
{
    sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " - Heat Number = " + Heat_Number);
    sw.Dispose();
}

Melt_Start = Convert.ToString(new SqlCommand("SQL Code to confidential db", conn).ExecuteScalar());
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("EventLog_SlagModel.txt"))
{
    sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " - Melt Start = " + Melt_Start);
    sw.Dispose();
}

Melt_End = Convert.ToString(new SqlCommand("SQL Code to confidential db", conn).ExecuteScalar());
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("EventLog_SlagModel.txt"))
{
    sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " - Melt End = " + Melt_End);
    sw.Dispose();
}

using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("EventLog_SlagModel.txt"))
{
    conn.Open();
    sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " - Connection Opened");

    using (var command = new SqlCommand("SQL Code to confidential db", conn))
    {
        Heat_Number = Convert.ToInt64(command.ExecuteScalar());
        sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " - Heat Number = " + Heat_Number);
        command.Parameters.Clear();

        command.CommandText = @"SQL Code to confidential db";
        Melt_Start = Convert.ToString(command.ExecuteScalar());
        sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " - Melt Start = " + Melt_Start);
        command.Parameters.Clear();
    }
}



You don't need sw.Dispose(). That's the whole point of a using block: it ensures it's called for you, and in a safer/more reliable way.

Oh, and you don't happen to have this text file open in another program, do you? Because that would cause this issue.

Do you have a AV running in the background? Opening and closing a file constantly for writing is doomed to trigger an AV and locking the file temporarily.

As this is in a timer can another thread of your application also have an open streamwriter for that file?

Is all the code you posted actually sequential in your app? If not, you should make that clear. If you comment out the File.WriteAllText call, do you still see that error message?

In my experience it can be problematic to frequently open/close a file, I'm not sure the file system is guaranteed to have released the file lock when .Dispose() returns. Regardless, you might want to consider using a library like nLog, serilog,log4net or similar for your logging needs.

I'm not sure the file system is guaranteed to have released the file lock when .Dispose() returns Of course it is. Closing a file is deterministic - it uses the Windows API CloseHandle() to close it. If it wasn't deterministic, all hell would break loose.

@JoelCoehoorn yes I am aware that is the purpose of the using block, but I added it anyways to be sure it wasn't the problem. Clearly that did not prevent the exception though...

@MartinSmith I have 3 timers, but only 1 runs at a time, and when it is triggered all timers are stopped then only 1 timer is restarted after the full script executes. This allows 2 different "live modes" to run at different times, and a "historical mode" which only updates the comboBox listing in the same stop-execute-start fashion.

@Ralf what do you mean an AV? I definitely open-write-close many many times... is there a better way to do this? Maybe using a library like nLog, serilog,log4net like JonasH mentioned

Its your log file so its best to keep it open over the programs lifetime and just flush the File regularly. The mentioned libraries will do so besides many other things that might help. AV = Antivirus Tool. They will typically scan files after handles are released and those are then locked for a short time. Many tools create that problem not just AVs. FileSyncing tools like DropBox or OneDrive can create the same problems.

For your added code SqlCommand is a Disposable you are leaking resources here.

the file is kept in a onedrive folder, should I change that as well? I included another code snippet above to show how I am retrieving then logging the information.

OneDrive is a problem yes. Putting it somewhere else and testing might help in confirming that that was the problem. Besides that just don't constantly open &close files.

@Ralf so like the added code snippet above? I am embedding both in a using block and executing sequentially still, but not opening/closing repeatedly.

@NDionise93 It would be better to (a) use a full path to the file (b) store that full path in a variable instead of writing it everywhere (c) accumulate the strings in a StringBuilder and then use File.WriteAllText.

@NDionise93 AV = anti-virus software.
